# Multiple plots in single PDF file using ggplot

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I am using the following code to save multiple plots in a single pdf file. Individual plots work well, but with a loop I get a corrupt file that doesn't have pages

```
pdf("HistogramsAll.pdf", onefile=TRUE)
for (i in 1:nFilt) {
d.i<-dAll[,c(1,i+1)];
nameP.i<-names(dAll)[i+1];
names(d.i)<-c("cond", "p");
    ggplot(data=d.i, aes(x=p, fill=cond))+
        geom_histogram(binwidth=.3, position="dodge")   +
    ggtitle(eval(nameP.i));
}
dev.off()
```

Comment: Do you need to explicitly `print()` the plots?

Comment: Yes, with print() it worked. Thanks

Comment: I've added this as an answer. If it solves your issue then please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/print.ggplot.html), an explicit `print()` is required inside a loop.

> Generally, you do not need to print or plot a ggplot2 plot explicitly:
>   the default top-level print method will do it for you. You will,
>   however, need to call print() explicitly if you want to draw a plot
>   inside a function or for loop.